# Geometric representation of the sum of a Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

Here is a geometric proof of why $\sum ar^{n}=\dfrac{a}{1-r}$ (|r|<1)-[Geometric Proof](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SumOfAGeometricSeries/)

which I find is quite intuitive.

Can someone give me a hint to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^{k}=\dfrac{a(1-r^{n})}{1-r}$  (k is finite,|r|<1) using similar geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometrical argument linked to works for $0\lt r\lt 1$.  It can be used to find the partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k$. Since the argument will use the infinite sum, again the geometry works only for $0\lt r\lt 1$.

The (infinite) sum, from the beginning to the end, is $\frac{a}{1-r}$.  And the *tail*, where we sum from $n$ to infinity, is $\frac{a}{1-r}$, **scaled** by the factor $r^n$. The difference between the whole sum and the tail is what we were after. It is
$$\frac{a}{1-r}-r^n\frac{a}{1-r},$$
exactly the desired result.

**Remark:** An amusing reversal! We ordinarily use the limit of partial sums to find the infinite sum. Here we used the geometry of the infinite sum to calculate the partial sum.